# Find the difference between two clearcase Labels (Need the newly created element as well)

Tags: linux, find, label, diff, clearcase

I would like to find the differences between two clearcase labels and I did use this before:

```
cleartool find -all -element "{lbtype_sub(!:1) && lbtype_sub(!:2)}" -version "{lbtype(!:2) && (! lbtype(!:1))}" -print
```

The problem for command above is:

- 1/ If there is any newly created/removed file,the file will not be printed. Only the higher directory name will be printed.

Ex:

```
For label 001:
/directoryA/:
a.cpp b.cpp 

For label 002: 
/directoryA/:
a.cpp b.cpp(new version) c.cpp(new element)
```

If we use the previous command, the printed result will only be

```
/directoryA@@.... 
/directoryA/b.cpp@@...
```

I would like a command to print the `c.cpp` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to complete your query with an additional separate query:

You could try to list all versions labeled `LBL2` AND *not* `LBL1` (i.e. new elements)

```
cleartool find -all -element "{(! lbtype_sub(!:1)) && lbtype_sub(!:2)}" -version "{lbtype(!:2)}" -print
```

Trying to do all in one command is difficult to do because you cannot easily combined all elements with 2 labels, with all elements with only the second label.

Comment: Hi:
Sorry for that I am the beginner in this clearcase file. The command you gave seem not work.

1. If I directly copied your command, and set it as an alias, it reports:

lbtype_sub: Event not found

I guess I need to use \! for someplaces, but after some changes, it still not works. Could you give a help to see if there shall be minor changes? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user2191818 I have changed the syntax. Before using it as an alias, try first using it directly, with your two label replacing `!:1` and `!:2`. If you already used your command mentioned in your question as an alias, then you would follow the same kind of escape style (`\`) for this new `find` command.